# React-Admin: How can I access a value without `source`?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to create a dynamic button in `react-admin`.
 
For each button it hits a unique address, how can I do that?

Unfortunately, I have this error: `props.username is undefined`.

```js
export const LoginCredentialList = (props) => (
  <List {...props} pagination={<PostPagination/>}>
    <Datagrid>
       <TextField label="Username" source="username" />
       <Button label="Re-invoke Login"
          onClick={() => {       
            axios.get("http://localhost:8080/admin/" + somehow_read_username_here)
                 .then((res)=>console.log(res));
             }}
        />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

Here is the `parent`, where the above component is being called or used:

```js
class SPanel extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Admin dataProvider={restDataProvider}>
          <Resource name="loginCredential" list={LoginCredentialList} />
            ...
```

Comment: please provide more details to the question

Comment: How are you passing the username property to your LoginCredentialList component?

Comment: updated please see @JatinParmar .. here is both of my components..

Comment: @krisaoe i'm not familiarized, can you tell me how to do so ??

Comment: @Danial how Resource render LoginCredentialList?

Comment: imported from another file.. @JatinParmar

Comment: So this might be a bit insulting if I'm wrong, but the error message `props.username is undefined` makes me wonder. Are you trying to access `props.username` or `this.props.username`?

Comment: can you post your `restProvider` code as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not worked with `react-admin` before, but after quickly skimming through its documentation what I understnad is that

- the `props` you receive in your `LoginCredentialList` component has list of records
- `Datagrid` iterates over this list and passes individual `record` to children `Field` components
- `Field` components receives `record` as prop injected by `react-admin`

Though `react-admin` provides many standard `Field` components, it does not have a `ButtonField`.

So you can write your own `Field` component. (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component)

Something like:

```
const ButtonField = ({source, record}) => (
    <Button label="Re-invoke Login" onClick={()=>{
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:8080/admin/"+record[source])
            .then((res)=>console.log(res));
    }}/>
);
```

And then use it your main component as

```
export const LoginCredentialList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} pagination={<PostPagination/>}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField label="Username" source="username" />
            <ButtonField source="username" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Try this out.